# build phonegap app for specific Android sdk

Tags: android, cordova

I installed Android 5.1 api, 5.0.1, 4.4.

When I build my test app, Phonegap uses 5.0.1 sdk.
How can build my test app with 4.4? I read the doc for build command but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest file you should have something like the below which defines sdk versions

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

more info here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html